# Understanding about creating a DFA

Tags: finite-automata

This is a school assignment, I am fairly new to DFA's.

```
L = {ww|w∈{0,1}*
```

I feel like I need to put this in words to understand how it works.

Translating L:

> W can be a string of an infinite combination of 1s and 0s.
>   WW is just a string that repeats itself.

For example W="101011",  WW = "101011101011".

Im not a 100% on this. Not really sure how to create a DFA out of
this.

Am I correct with my "translation"? If you can help me further into
making a DFA much appreciated.

Comment: Your language is not regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a DFA for this language because its not a Regular language
in fact its not even a context free language so you can't even make a PDA for it

to prove its not regular and not  context free you should use pumping lemma

but you can make a linear bounded automata for this language so therefore its a context sensitive language

hint for the linear bounded automata: put both of the w's in the tape and separate  them with 0, then compare them.

also here's some examples for some of the strings in the language :

00 , 11 , 0101 , 1010 , 110110 ...